# Cannot infer type for type parameter T, when the type is explicitly specified in a struct definition

Tags: pointers, rust, non-nullable

I have a struct definition which includes, among other things, this field:

```rust
pub struct Separated<'a, I, T>
{
    ..., // other fields,
    separated: NonNull<dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>>,
}
```

Shortly after, in its constructor, I attempt to initialize that field as a dangling pointer:

```rust
let sep = Separated {
    ..., // other fields
    separated: NonNull::dangling(),
};
```

This, weirdly, produces this error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
   |
16 |             separated: NonNull::dangling(),
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`
```

There's nothing mysterious about that field; its type is explicitly set in the struct definition. I do not understand why the type inferencer cannot infer an appropriate type to inject there.

A minimal 20-line example producing this error can be found below and [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f9aa45641c2029dc12ab6e5ae56e74c):

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::ptr::NonNull;

pub struct Separated<'a, T> {
    t: &'a T,
    separated: NonNull<dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Separated<'a, T>
where
    T: 'a + Copy + PartialEq,
{
    fn new(t: &'a T) -> Pin<Box<Self>> {
        let sep = Separated {
            t,
            separated: NonNull::dangling(),
        };
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

I do need `separated` to be a pointer to a trait object instead of a monomorphized type: the real trait object which it will contain is composed of a bunch of iterator combinators, including ones like `Map` and `TakeWhile`, whose types include function pointers and are therefore unnameable.

`NonNull::dangling` is not a parametric function: the `NonNull<T>` struct is parametric, but this function is not. Therefore, I can't just turbofish my way out of this. I'm not sure how I'd go about providing type annotations at all.

---

Context, if useful: the whole reason I'm going down this path is I am attempting to create an iterator combinator, auto-implemented for all appropriate iterators, which injects a single element between each N elements of the origin iterator. It's not all that hard to accomplish for a single iterator, but much harder to do as a generic combinator, because the `IntoChunks` struct produced by Itertools' `chunks()` combinator is not itself an iterator, just a struct implementing `IntoIterator`. Therefore, we need to keep track of the `IntoChunks` struct as well as the iterator it produces.

The approach I'm taking is to create a self-referential struct, `Separated`, which contains both of those. This should be safe assuming the struct is always pinned. I then `impl Iterator for Separated` and just defer the `next` calls to `self.separated`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the standard docs, the definition of [`NonNull::dangling()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.dangling) is this:

> ```rust
> impl<T> NonNull<T> {
>   pub const fn dangling() -> NonNull<T> {
>     /* ... */
>   }
> }
> ```

And in your code, you're using it in a place where an expression with the type `NonNull<dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>>`, so the return value must have this type.

The subtle thing here is that generic type parameters have an implicit `Sized` bound (unless it has a `?Sized` bound). So because the implementation of `NonNull::dangling` does not have a `?Sized` bound, Rust will attempt to infer the type parameter of `NonNull` based on these requirements:

- Because the `NonNull::<T>::dangling()` method does not have a bound `T: ?Sized`, it is only implemented for sized types `T`, and the type parameter must be sized.
- The type parameter must be `dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>`.

However, because trait objects ("`dyn Trait` types") are unsized, it is impossible for Rust to satisfy both requirements at once, hence why it "cannot infer type for type parameter `T`".

---

In fact, by explicitly adding the type to your playground example, you'll get a different error message that's more explicit about the problem:

```rust
let sep = Separated::<'a, T> {
  t,
  separated: NonNull::<dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>>::dangling(),
};
```

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `dangling` found for type `std::ptr::NonNull<(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = T> + 'a)>` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:16:64
   |
16 |             separated: NonNull::<dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>>::dangling(),
   |                                                                ^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `std::ptr::NonNull<(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = T> + 'a)>`
   |
   = note: the method `dangling` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = T> : std::marker::Sized`
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very informative. Unfortunately, I can't say it's helpful, because it doesn't get me any closer to a working implementation. Adding a `+?Sized` bound doesn't work; those aren't permitted in trait objects. Is it truly the case that I can only accomplish this with raw pointers?

Comment: Nevermind, after a bit of thought, you did lead me to the right answer: I just need to create a temporary function pointer of appropriate type (in this case, `let temporary_iter: *mut _ = &mut std::iter::once(t)`), and initialize `separated` with `NonNull::new_unchecked`, which _does_ work for `?Sized`.

Comment: @coriolinus `NonNull` implements `CoerceUnsized`, which means you can do something like `NonNull::<std::iter::Empty<T>>::dangling()` and the compiler will coerce the `NonNull<Empty<T>>` to a `NonNull<dyn 'a + Iterator<Item = T>>`.